# git push not reflected on repo

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github

I am pushing to my servers repo and the push is successful as seen below. I am able to successfully pull code from the server, but any pushes I make are not reflected on the server's repo.

This is the push message:

```
git push deploy master
Counting objects: 25, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 2.63 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 25 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ec2-user@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~/proj/.git 4846465..9facf35  master -> master
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` show you?  You only need the portion where you're looking at `deploy/master` and `master` for this one.

Comment: What makes you sure that the server did not get updated? Try `git ls-remote deploy master`. If it shows `9facf35` then it was updated. Maybe you are looking at a different repository on the same server.

Comment: I just restarted my server and it works now. Thanks for the help